# Assignment of Different Values to Single Variable each Iteration

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, variable-assignment

There is a list `s` and two variables `m` and `n`:

```
s = [3, 'abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789']
```

`s[0]` is type int. It represents the number of times an iteration should occur to assign the following values to m and n. 
Ex:
This list of s should be iterated 3 times as denoted by `s[0]`. Each iteration should assign a new value from s to m and n.

First iteration, m and n should be assigned

```
m = 'abc'
n = '123'
```

Second iteration,

```
m = 'def' 
n = '123'`
```

third iteration,

```
m = 'ghi' 
n = '789'
```

What I have tried so far -

```
s = [3, 'abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789']

count = 0
i = 0
j = 2
while count < s[0]:
     m = s[i+1]
     n = s[j+1]
     print(m)
     print(n)
     count += 1
     i += 1
     j += 1
```

My ouput is

```
abc
def
123
456
def
ghi
```

instead of

```
abc 
123
def
456
ghi
789
```

Please help me to build the needed logic to get through this.

Comment: i think you miswrote the second iteration in the initial opener. `n=456` ? Regardless, Just focus on one variable for a second, say `m`. Can you write/speak out loud what index `m` uses in each iteration? Once you do that, look at your variables being incremented. `i += 1` ? Do you see the problem?

Comment: Yes understood your logic. So I set i=1 and j=2 and then ran out of range in the end after two iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
s = [3, 'abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789']
i = 1
count=1
while  count<=s[0]:
      m = s[i]
      n = s[i+1]
      print(m)
      print(n)
      i += 2
      count+=1
```

the indices i, j must be incremented two by two, on the other hand, only one of them is needed, since the value of j at all times would be i + 1.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use an iterator and you won't have to manage indexes at all:

```
it = iter(s)
for _ in range(next(it)):
    m, n = next(it), next(it)
    print(m)
    print(n)
```

Or using index access:

```
i, j = 1, 2
for _ in range(s[0]):
    m, n = s[i], s[j]
    print(m)
    print(n)
    i, j = i+2, j+2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that we can simplify this by saying that in our loop the loop counter is equal to `s[0]*2`. This way we can define loop step to be `2`. But this means that `s[0]` **has to** be smaller or equal to `(len(s) -1)/2`

```
>>> s = [3, 'abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789']
>>> for i in range(1, s[0]*2, 2):
    print(s[i])
    print(s[i+1])


abc
123
def
456
ghi
789
```

Parameters to this range are:

- First index = 1
- Max index = 6
- Increment each step = 2

So first loop we get `i = 1` and we print indexes `1` and `2`, then the index becomes `3` and we print `3` and `4`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Its convenient when you make it work where one variable is == 0. Then to assign m and n you can follow and understand example below:

```
count = 0
for itervar in [3, 41, 12, 9, 74, 15]:
    count = count + 1
print 'Count: ', count
```

then

```
total = 0
for itervar in [3, 41, 12, 9, 74, 15]:
    total = total + itervar
print 'Total: ', total
```

You can increase the number of iterations you want.